# gpg failed to sign the data, failed to write commit object

Tags: git, gpg, github, gpg-agent

I have searched the whole universe this error but i could not find any helpful tips.

I have created a key using keybase and added my public key to github gpg

my `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG`
is this

```
--------------------------------
sec   rsa4096/7E8*******60B47B 2021-03-06 [SC] [expires: 2037-03-02]
      51FBCD0E******************014D4860B47B
uid                 [ultimate] Fatih <********@live.be>
uid                 [ultimate] Fatih <73314940+kgnfth@users.noreply.github.com>
ssb   rsa4096/15BBF8A123C4AC1B 2021-03-06 [E] [expires: 2037-03-02]
```

my `.gitconfig is this`

```
[user]
        signingkey = 7E8*******60B47B
        email = 73314940+kgnfth@users.noreply.github.com
        name = kgnfth
[commit]
        gpgsign = true
[gpg]
        program = gpg
```

i added `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` to my .zshrc file

Everytime i run git commit -m "first commit",
i get this error

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I dont see anything wrong with the signing key
i also tried changing gpg to gpg2 but the same error appears

i am out of idea
i need your help

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you create a key using gpg and then use that key, it might be an issue with the keybase key

Comment: keybase uses your installed gpg program it has nothing to do with it
i fixed my issue by adding gpg-agent plugin to my zshrc config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved my issue by adding gpg-agent plugin to my zshrc config file.

Comment: Any chance you can provide more detail on how to do what you did to fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickSteil see here https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/gpg-agent

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by the Accepted answer, Adding gpg-agent to the zsh plugins solves the problem. I later found out that exporting `GPG_TTY` is enough to make it work.

Add below line to .zshrc or .zprofile(prefer)

```
export GPG_TTY=$TTY
```

For extra detail, gpg seems to output the pin-entry process onto some other external source and not the current terminal being used. **TTY** holds the ref to the current terminal and thus exporting it as **GPG_TTY** solves the problem in this case.

Comment: Right, the zsh plugin does the same.